# ruby script explanation please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i know nothing about ruby, can anyone help explaining what this script is doing please?

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 begin
    require '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler'
    # Check if an older version of bundler is installed(this part i understand)
    $:.each do |path|
    if path =~ %r'/bundler-0.(\d+)' && $1.to_i < 9
       err = "Please remove Bundler 0.8 versions."
       err << "This can be done by running `gem cleanup bundler`."
       abort(err)
    end
  end
  #it is from here that i dont understand
  require '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/cli'
  Bundler::CLI.start
  rescue Bundler::BundlerError => e
    Bundler.ui.error e.message
    Bundler.ui.debug e.backtrace.join("\n")
  exit e.status_code
  rescue Interrupt => e
    Bundler.ui.error "\nQuitting..."
    Bundler.ui.debug e.backtrace.join("\n")
    exit 1
  end
```

here my irb test:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/bin$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'bundler'
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler
from (irb):1:in `require'
from (irb):1
from :0
irb(main):002:0> require 'bundler/cli'
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler/cli
from (irb):2:in `require'
from (irb):2
from :0
irb(main):003:0> Bundler::CLI.start
NameError: uninitialized constant Bundler
from (irb):3
from :0
irb(main):004:0>
```

thanks

Comment: yup i get error:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/bin/bundle:14:in `rescue in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler::BundlerError (NameError)
is this why the bundler cli dont want to start because of the above? thanks

Comment: `require '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler'` is presumably the line that is failing, then.  Is there a file at that location?

Comment: yes an executable called bundle: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  699 2012-02-14 09:48 bundle

Comment: You need to run `gem install bundler` if `require 'bundler'` fails. You also need to make sure that the paths make sense on *your* system. And there's no reason to run it from the `bundler` directory, if you want it to *do* anything there needs to be a `Gemfile` in the directory, like a rails app. What are you even trying to do? Why are you doing any of this?

Comment: i am trying to figure out why my project does not want to build using jenkins. In jenkins when you click on configure on the left hand side it opens up the configurations settings on the right. if you scroll down to under the build section there is a script that runs. the build fails. if you now go to the console output of the failed build it shows: bundle install --path vendor/gems --binstubs /tmp/hudson4637677486807131064.sh: 1: bundle: not found thus the build failed. sudo gem install bundler gave: [sudo] password for helloises: Successfully installed bundler-1.0.22 1 gem installed

Comment: i also have an empty Gemfile in my root dir: /github_mira/rainbow_code$ ls -lah Gemfile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 helloises helloises 2 2012-02-14 14:30 Gemfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to start the bundler CLI, and if it gets a BundlerError or is interrupted it'll print the stacktrace and exit with a status code. Run the same code from an irb in a directory with a Gemfile and see what happens. It'll look like what happens if you do a `bundle install` from the command line.

---

```
$ irb
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > require 'bundler'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 > require 'bundler/cli'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > Bundler::CLI.start
```

Comment: yikes i dont know how to do that i have never worked with this stuff. it is beyond my scope..please how do i do: Run the same code from an irb in a directory with a Gemfile?

Comment: @charlie_cat See edited answer. You go to a directory with a Gemfile, type `irb`, require the things required, and type in the code you want to run. However, if it "beyond your scope", you should take the time to understand what you're doing, and why.

Comment: i posted my output in my main post :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you don't understand... can you be more specific?

But the `rescue` bit is a clause relating to the `begin` earlier on.  It's like try/catch in Java, if that means anything to you.

It means, "try doing all the stuff between `begin` and `end`, but if a `BundlerError` happens, then do this, and if a `Interrupt` error happens, do that"

Does that answer your question?